# onEachSide() in pagination not working in Laravel 6.16.0

Tags: laravel

This is my action:

```
public function look(int $id)
{
    $key = Key::findOrFail($id);
    $data = $key->class_name::paginate(100);
    return view('look', compact('data'));
}
```

This is a part of view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        {{ $data->onEachSide(7)->links() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) says:

> You may control how many additional links are displayed on each side of the paginator's URL "window". By default, three links are displayed on each side of the primary paginator links. However, you may control this number using the onEachSide method.

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my mistake, I have too few records in database :)

Comment: is it your answer?

Comment: @Sabbir, yes, I was inattentive.